# are fourier coefficients always symmetric?

Tags: fourier-analysis

this may sound like a dumb question but are fourier coefficients always symmetric?

ie $\hat{f}(n) = \hat{f}(-n)$?

Comment: You should consider the  Fourier coefficients of $e^{ix}$, for example.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Consider $f(x)=e^{ix}$, or polynomials in this $f$.

Comment: ok i guess i have another dumb question: if i take the derivative of $e^{inx}$, do i get $ine^{inx}$ or $ne^{inx}$

Comment: @jack: The chain rule still applies to complex valued functions, and it's easy to show that the derivative of $x\mapsto inx$ is $in$.

Comment: so i guess it should be $ine^{inx}$, is that right?

Comment: Yes.${}{}{}{}{}$

Answer (score 5):

The answer is no, as Jonas Meyer pointed out.  However, if $f$ is a *real-valued* function, then the real parts of the Fourier coefficients will be symmetric, and the imaginary parts antisymmetric:

$\operatorname{Re}(\hat{f}(n))=\operatorname{Re}(\hat{f}(-n))$

$\operatorname{Im}(\hat{f}(n))=-\operatorname{Im}(\hat{f}(-n))$

Comment: Hence for real, even functions equality holds. The equality also holds for some complex functions.

Answer (score 0):

You might like to consider the difference:
$$\hat{f}(n)-\hat{f}(-n)=\frac{1}{2\pi}\int_{-\pi}^\pi f(t)e^{-int}dt-\frac{1}{2\pi}\int_{-\pi}^\pi f(t)e^{int}dt=\frac{1}{2\pi}\int_{-\pi}^\pi f(t)(e^{-int}-e^{int})dt$$
Next, note from the Euler equations that $e^{-int}-e^{int}=-2i\cdot \sin(nt)$.

Hence $\hat{f}(n)=\hat{f}(-n)$ (for some $n$) means that $f$ is *orthogonal* to (or rather, that $f$ is annihilated by) the function $t\mapsto\sin(nt)$ (for some $n$).